# List users whose accounts isn't locked

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, aix

I have created a script which lists list of users from the server and emails them.

I can get the user list from multiple host, and also it filters a file called ignore.txt (which has unwanted users) before sending the list.

The challenge is now, that `/etc/passwd` has users whose account are locked (not active). Is it possible to edit the script below and send a list of users who are active, and aslo a list of users whose account is locked?

The new report should reflect a list of active users and also a list of disabled/locked users.

My current script is the following:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#title                :user.list.script.ksh
#description     :This script collects list of users from the server
#note               :Multiple hosts can be added



#HOSTS format:
HOSTS="00.00.00.00-DEV" #example "hostname-DEV"

FILE=/home/zaira/report.txt #list will be saved in report.txt

date > $FILE
echo >> $FILE

for host in $HOSTS; do
  ip=$(echo $host|cut -d '-' -f 1)
  title=$(echo $host|cut -d '-' -f 2)

  ssh $ip -q -l zaira cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{printf("%-30s\t%-30s\t%-40s\n                                                                             ", $1, $3, $5)}'  >/tmp/temp 2>/dev/null
  echo "$title instance" >> $FILE
  perl -e 'print "=" x 65,"\n"' >>$FILE
#we filter through ignore.list to remove unwanted users
  cat /tmp/temp|grep -wvf /home/zaira/ignore.list|sort >> $FILE
  echo >> $FILE
done

rm -f /tmp/temp

mailx -r From-DEV-no-reply@abc.com -s " User list" zairabanu@abc.com <  "$FILE"
```

Comment: @林果皞  any idea on how can it be performed

Comment: It is hard to say, how exactly your locking mechanism works. Sometimes te "password" field gets to a `*`, sometimes the same happen in the `/etc/shadow`. Knowing this your problem would be easy.

Comment: @ peterh its an AIX server./etc/security/user
. The /etc/security/user file contains the most important settings, outside of the basics in /etc/passwd, for a user.  Parameters in the /etc/security/user file
Parameter Format Description
account_locked TRUE | FALSE Lock out the account; the user is unable to log in if set to True.
   We lock account by running chuser account_locked=true USERNAME ..  for example user sshd in /etc/security/user file has....................  sshd:
        admin = false
        account_locked = true
        login = false
        rlogin = false

Comment: Even on AIX are there many ways to do that.

Comment: Don't forget that an invalid login shell (`/bin/foosh`) or a non-shell (`/bin/false`) will also "lock" an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from memory, as it's been a loo,ooo,ooo,ong time since I've used AIX, you can use `lsuser` to get locked accounts:

```
lsuser -a account_locked ALL | grep '=true$' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

If you don't want to manually maintain an ignore list, you can get a list of those users who can log in:

```
lsuser -a login ALL | grep '=true$' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

With respect to the OP original script, you can probably now do something like:

```
lsuser -a login ALL | grep '=true$' | awk '{ print $1 }' > /tmp/temp
```

Actually modifying the original script is left up to the OP.

Comment: `smitty` might also be able to do it, don't remember.

Comment: this will give you usres whose accounts are locked.Some of them are not real users like sshd Thats one of the reason i have created ignore.list to filter through it and remove unreal users.

Comment: @Zairabanu Then perhaps you want the `login` attribute. I'll update my answer.

Comment: is it possible to modify existing script and make it send a list of active users and also list of inactive users(accounts are locked).As i need both list

Comment: @Zairabanu Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Zairabanu That's not how SO works.  For the question you asked, about getting locked users, I've answered your question.  Up-vote and accept.  Then try integrating it into your script.  If you have problems, then ask another question.

Comment: Thank you .i will try to integrate